# mask list/tensor with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, list, pytorch, mask, tensor

The following code masks fine

```py
mask = targets >= 0
targets = targets[mask]
```

However, when I try masking with two conditions, it gives an error of `RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous`

```py
mask = (targets >= 0 and targets <= 5)
targets = targets[mask]
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: change brackets to `(targets>=0) & (targets<=5)` to take `and` between 2 arrays, details in my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making a mistake while using brackets. Bracket around each of the conditions so that NumPy considers them as individual arrays.

```
targets = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,))

mask = (targets>=0) & (targets<=5) #<----------

print(mask)
targets[mask]
```

```
[ True False  True False False  True  True  True False  True]
array([4, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3])
```

---

You can create some complex logic using multiple masks and then directly index an array with them. Example - XNOR can be written as `~(mask1 ^ mask2)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.logical_and` to create a mask for conjunction since it returns a new mask that combines both conditions instead of returning a boolean.

```py
targets = np.array([-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
mask = np.logical_and(targets >= 0, targets <= 5) # == [0,1,1,1,1,1,0]

print(targets[mask]) # [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Edit: I see that you're using pytorch, the process is basically the same, simply use `torch.logical_and`.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly good answer! Since I only could accept one, I accepted Akshay's cause I feel like his is marginally cleaner.